# Accessing a string out of bounds does not trigger any valgrind/ASAN/UBSAN warnings

Tags: unicode, glib, vala

I have this code:

```
static int main(string[] args) {
        info(escape_latex(args[1]));
        return 0;
}
string escape_latex(string input) {
        var builder = new StringBuilder.sized(input.length + 20);
        var map = new Gee.HashMap<string, string>();
        // ...<Snip>...
        // Fix for some weird unicode bugs
        map["\xff\xbf\xbf\xbf\xbf\xbf"] = "";
        info("Len: %d", input.char_count());
        for(var i = 0; i < input.char_count(); i++) {
                var ic = input.get_char(i);
                var as_string = ic.to_string();
                info("%d %s", i, as_string);
                if(map.has_key(as_string)) {
                        builder.append(map[as_string]);
                } else {
                        builder.append_unichar(ic);
                }
        }
        return builder.str;
}
```

If I pass "foo123", I get the expected output "foo123". But If I pass "Geldbeutel+Schlüsselanhänger", I get the output "Geldbeutel+Schl?sselanh?ng" (Last two chars are missing).

Now I changed the for-loop to `for(var i = 0; i <= input.char_count(); i++) {`

For "foo123", I get the expected output, for "Geldbeutel+Schlüsselanhänger", I get "Geldbeutel+Schl?sselanh?nge". (Valgrind, ASAN and UBSAN don't show anything).

Now I change the for-loop to `for(var i = 0; i <= input.char_count() + 1; i++) {`

"foo123" is now `foo123G`, as I run over into other memory, but "Geldbeutel+Schlüsselanhänger" give the correct output "Geldbeutel+Schl?sselAnh?nger"

For the last example input, an example output:

```
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:23: Len: 28
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 0 G
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 1 e
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 2 l
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 3 d
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 4 b
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 5 e
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 6 u
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 7 t
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 8 e
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 9 l
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 10 +
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 11 S
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 12 c
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 13 h
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 14 l
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 15 ?
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 17 s
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 18 s
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 19 e
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 20 l
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 21 a
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 22 n
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 23 h
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 24 ?
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 26 n
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 27 g
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 28 e
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:29: 29 r            // <- Here, I access an invalid index, but it works
** INFO: 19:41:57.903: a.vala:2: Geldbeutel+Schl?sselanh?nger
```

It seems to be related to unicode, but I can't find a way to make this function work.

Comment: Are you missing any essential information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is to do with the locale and the default for the C runtime environment is US ASCII. You can set it to the user preferred locale for the runtime environment by passing an empty string to [`Intl.setlocale()`](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.Intl.setlocale.html) for `LocaleCategory.ALL`, which are also the default parameter values, so `Intl.setlocale();` will work:

```vala
static int main(string[] args) {
        Intl.setlocale();
        print(escape_latex(args[1]) + "\n");
        return 0;
}
string escape_latex(string input) {
        var builder = new StringBuilder.sized(input.length + 20);
        var map = new Gee.HashMap<string, string>();
        // ...<Snip>...
        // Fix for some weird unicode bugs
        map["\xff\xbf\xbf\xbf\xbf\xbf"] = "";
        info("Len: %d", input.char_count());
        for(var i = 0; i < input.char_count(); i++) {
                var ic = input.get_char(i);
                var as_string = ic.to_string();
                info("%d %s", i, as_string);
                if(map.has_key(as_string)) {
                        builder.append(map[as_string]);
                } else {
                        builder.append_unichar(ic);
                }
        }
        return builder.str;
}
```